# Update таблицы T-SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Всех приветствую. Я пытаюсь создать приложение, которое работает с базой данных. Я использую Winform для графики и Microsoft SQL Server 2019 для БД. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой. При попытке обновления данных, в базе данных, происходит обновление всех строк сразу. Как можно сделать так чтобы обновлялась только нужная(выделенная строка). Для вывода данных из БД я использую DataGridView.
Код используемый мной для обновления:

```
    UPDATE       Logins
SET                Login = @Login, Pass = @Pass
```

Comment: Это самые основы sql, потратьте 10 минут вашего времени на любой гайд по sql и там все это объясняется.

Comment: У вас обновляют все потому что у вас нет условия на обновление записей. Добавьте фильтр и сьузте количество записей и будет всё хорошо. Where ID=@Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у оператора UPDATE не указаны какие-то ограничивающие условия (например, WHERE), то он обновляет все строки таблицы.
Поэтому в вашем случае нужно передать в него идентификатор той строки, которую вы ходите обновить. Например,

```
UPDATE Logins
SET Login = @Login, Pass = @Pass
WHERE ID = @Id
```

Соответственно, когда вы заполняете DataGridView вам нужно ещё считывать идентификаторы нужных строк (в примере – значение поля ID), чтобы потом передать их в скрипт обновления

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался в чём проблема. Немножко напутал при составлении базы данных